# How to write unclosed HTML statements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In writing some JavaScript for a project, I've run into a problem. I need to create a couple of Div elements, clone a selection list and then close the Divs. Using innerHTML has the side-effect of automatically closing any "open" HTML statements that are left hanging. Here's an example:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '<i>This should be <b>bold ';
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '</b> and this should not</i>';
</script>
</body></html>
```

When this is executed by a browser, the italic and bold from the first innerHTML assignment are automatically "closed" for me. What can I do to keep them open?

Comment: Some people might disagree, but I would say, you could always check with syntax highlighter IDE/tool for you html code. It's human nature to do a typo :)

Comment: as soon as you insert invalid markup into the dom, the dom fixes it, adding the msising close tags so that by the time you add the closer, it's alread been closed, and you've been appending after the close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be using *appendChild* for other things and need to insert DOM objects into the document, you should consider something like:

```
var myDiv, span;
myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'boldClass';
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('This should be bold'));
div.appendChild(span);

// Add other DOM objects here

span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'notBoldClass';
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' and this should not'));
div.appendChild(span);
```

You can have a function that returns DOM elements based on passed parameters, e.g.

```
function makeElement(tagName, props) {
  var el = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (var p in props) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      el[p] = props[p];
    }
  }
  return el;
}
```

so then you can do things like:

```
span = makeElement('span', {className: 'boldClass'});
```

Note that there are a few quirks to deal with so do some research and test thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you RobG. You actually read my post and answered my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Don't assign to innerHTML until you have finishing building the HTML string. Either use a temporary variable:

```
var h = '';
h += '<i>This should be <b>bold ';
h += '</b> and this should not</i>';
myDiv.innerHTML = h;
```

Or assign the strings in one expression:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = 
    '<i>This should be <b>bold ' +
    '</b> and this should not</i>';
```

Comment: Perhaps I've over-simplified too much. In my more-complex actual problem, there's a bit of code that in between the two innerHTML statements that I left out. That code creates a select list by copying another. That code uses "appendChild" statements to do the copies. Is there then a way to use appendChild to append to my string before turning it loose on innerHTML?

Comment: @DavidSpencer—no. *innerHTML* is text, *appendChild* requires DOM objects. Seems to me you shouldn't be using innerHTML at all and instead should be putting the text in span elements with appropriate styles using say the *class* attribute.

Comment: @DavidSpencer, this answers the question that was actually asked. If you have a more complicated question, please ask it separately, after accepting this answer. This question now seems to draw attention partly due to the typo, `</b>` for `<b>`, which has not been corrected in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid inner html:

```
'<i>This should be </b>bold '
--------------------^ it is opening tag not closing, remove the /
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have a mistake on using tags, you have double `</b>` the first `b` tag should be `<b>`

```
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '<i>This should be </b>bold ';
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '</b> and this should not</i>';
```

---

```
When this is executed by a browser, the italic and bold from the first innerHTML assignment are automatically "closed" for me. What can I do to keep them open?
```

I suggest that you put them to a variable first before updating the `innerHTML`

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var htmlstring = '<i>This should be <b>bold ';
htmlstring += '</b> and this should not</i>';

myDiv.innerHTML += htmlstring;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't get why this was down voted, I guess others might have better answers? Please site my mistake before you down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the essence of the question was whether `innerHTML` can be used to insert locally invalid HTML sequences, which it can't. Simply changing the problem to make the individual HTML sequences valid doesn't really answer the underlying question.

Comment: Whoever downvoted should well know how that **HURTS** and fight the temptation to `click` on the *Down* arrow

Comment: You're missing the point. I simplified my example so I could demonstrate an unanticipated result.

Comment: @DavidSpencer I updated my answer, please check code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is not well formed

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '<i>This should be <b>bold ';
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + '</b> and this should not</i>';
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I've simplified my problem too far. I was attempting to demonstrate the unanticipated results that I was receiving.